# Set the "From Address" as same email that created the case

Tags: apex, email2case

```
//Purpose: Set default from Address on Cases

    //SRC:https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cases_email_apex_default_fields.htm&type=5&release=214
    global class emailQuickActionHelper implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
    // Empty constructor
    global emailQuickActionHelper() {
    }
    
    // The main interface method
    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(0);
        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject(); 
        
        Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Origin FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
        EmailServicesAddress E = [SELECT Id,AuthorizedSenders,EmailDomainName,IsActive,LocalPart 
                                  FROM EmailServicesAddress];
        
            
            //emailMessage.FromName = e.FromAddress;
            emailMessage.ValidatedFromAddress = e.EmailDomainName;
            system.debug('Case Number' + c.CaseNumber);
            system.debug('Email From Address:' + e.EmailDomainName);
               
    } 
}
```

When a user that would handle cases uses the email quick action
[image]

so if the case was created using Email-To-Case
and the routing address is test@test.com

then I would want the drop down to default to test@test.com

I think both of my queries get the data I would need but I couldn't figure out how to get the EmailServiceAddress related to the case.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the EmailServicesAddress references the forwarding email address that is used by your email system to route emails.  So I'm unclear about why you want to use that address as the sender address in your quick action.

However, the EmailMessage object may be of better use.  On the EmailMessage object are two fields:

ParentId - which references the ID of the case that’s associated with the email

FromAddress - which references the address that originated the email.

Rather than querying for EmailServicesAddress, instead query the EmailMessage records and specify the caseId in the where clause.

SELECT Id, FromAddress, ParentId from EmailMessage where ParentId =: c.Id]

Comment: yeah so I want to to query for the EmailServiceAddress used to create the case

right now I'm getting an out of bound error because it's querying for every single email

Comment: Ah I see, updated my answer.